# EXCEL: Conditional Formatting Using Row Not Working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an Excel Sheet that I need to conditionally format so I can tell how close numbers in the cells are to the midpoint of a range.  These are the rules:

Blanks = WHITE

Values outside of my desired range (Rows B and C) = RED

Values inside of my desired range will scale with the midpoint = GREEN and the outer points = YELLOW

Format Rules
[image]

If I make a separate condition on every row, it is CORRECT and looks like this:

Correct
[image]

But that would take an insane amount of time to create rules for every row.

If I make the following formula to try to speed things up, it calculates correctly for the first row and then incorrectly for the remaining rows (only using the numbers from the first row).

3-Color Scale Example:

Minimum =INDIRECT("B"&RIGHT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1),LEN(ROW())))

Midpoint =(INDIRECT("B"&RIGHT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1),LEN(ROW())))+INDIRECT("C"&RIGHT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1),LEN(ROW()))))/2

Maximum =INDIRECT("C"&RIGHT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1),LEN(ROW())))

Incorrect:
[image]

Comment: Where are rows B and C in your examples? Do both screen captures start at ROW A? It looks like that's can't be the case since I assume "Normal" is not one of your desired values. Can you also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51775034/edit) your question with the conditions you use for a single row?

Comment: You realize your first format rule applies to the range `=$E$3:$O$56` and the other two rows apply only to `$E$3:$O$3`?

Comment: The Range is Rows B and C.  So for example, B3=1.1 and C3=2.5.  Row 3's numbers are supposed to be based on those.  Yes, the first rule just White's out all blanks and does not need to be applied row by row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color scales don't accept relative references in the value formulas. You'll have to bite the bullet and use absolute references and adjust the row number for each row.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad that you understand the question perfectly.  Are you sure that there's not some clever formula that can get this accomplished?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that Excel can do this with the out of the box color scale feature. You may want to employ VBA to automate the formula adjustments for each row.